# How to install pgstattuple extension in postgres 10.6?

Tags: postgresql

Can someone let me know how to install `pgstattuple` extension in postgres 10.6 running on Ubuntu 16?

I have installed `postgres-contrib` and can see the following sql under `extension` folder

```
ubuntu@vrni-proxy:~$ ls /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple*
/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple--1.0--1.1.sql  /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple--1.3--1.4.sql  /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple.control
/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple--1.1--1.2.sql  /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple--1.4--1.5.sql  /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple--1.2--1.3.sql  /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/pgstattuple--1.4.sql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CREATE EXTENSION — loads a new extension into the current database.

So, you could do something like:

CREATE EXTENSION pgstattuple;